# Formula not working in Excel to move to SharePoint calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, excel

I have two conditions that need to be met to return a date in another column

Here is my formula
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Rejected",A2)) =IF(isblank,"","Today"))

I can't get this to work, if i do them seperate they work but not together.

Any help would be appreciated.
Dorinda

Answer (score 1):

You have an "=" where you need a ",".

If an IF/ELSE then change to:

```
=IF( ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Rejected",A2)), IF(isblank,"","Today"), "else???" )
```

If this is an OR or AND test then:

```
=OR( IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Rejected",A2))), IF(isblank,"","Today") )
```

What is "isblank"? A column name? Or should this be ISBLANK(something)

Answer (score 1):

There shall be some differences between Excel formula and SharePoint formula.

Would you like to share us a bit more information about your list and how the formula shall work?

I assume your formula is like to be

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Rejected","the column name where you want to search")), IF(isblank("the column name where you want to check if it is blank"),"Today", " "),"")
```

It will return "today" if both conditions are met, or just return blank

Some information about the functions you used:
[IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a)  [Search function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/search-function-f79ef0b8-0991-4fc1-93b0-627f019a69e3)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both I got this working with this solution

=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Rejected",[Master Data Review Decision])),[Master Data Rejection Comments]<>""),TODAY(),"")

Comment: Glad to hear you get it work. Please mark your reply as answer to indicate the solution for other community members